# How to pass a constant variable to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

which one is a better design in the following scenario and why?

A:

```
stop_words = ['com1', 'com2'] 
    
def clean_text(text_tokens, stop_words):
    return [token for token in text_tokens if token not in stop_words]

clean_text(['hello', 'world', 'com1', 'com2'], stop_words)
```

B:

```
def clean_text(text_tokens):
    stop_words = ['com1', 'com2']
    return [token for token in text_tokens if token not in stop_words]

clean_text(['hello', 'world', 'com1', 'com2'])
```

C:

```
STOP_WORDS = ['com1', 'com2'] 
    
def clean_text(text_tokens):
    return [token for token in text_tokens if token not in STOP_WORDS]

clean_text(['hello', 'world', 'com1', 'com2'])
```

*Added C version based on @MisterMiyagi answer.*

Note1: In this context, stop_words is fixed and does not change.

Note2: stop_words can be a small or a very large list.

Comment: If it does not change, you don't need a parameter for it. If you want to be future-proof, use A with `stop_words=None` anf `if stop_words is None: stop_words = ['com1', 'com2']`

Comment: To complete, there is also "middle" approach: default argument: `clean_text(text_tokens, stop_words=['com1', 'com2']):`. It does not pollute the global scope, but the expression is evaluated only once. Consider making it D option in the question :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Middle ground: use a default value for the argument.

```
def clean_text(text_tokens, stop_words={'com1', 'com2'}):
    return [token for token in text_tokens if token not in stop_words]

clean_text(['hello', 'world', 'com1', 'com2'])
```

Now the constant `{'com1', 'com2'}` is only created once (when the function is defined); it doesn't pollute the global scope; and if you end up wanting to, you can optionally pass different `stop_words` when you call `clean_text`.

Answer (score 4):

Prefer to create constants at global scope. The global scope is evaluated *once*, whereas function-local scope is evaluated *on each function call*.

For very large searches, prefer to use a `set` due to its O(1) lookup, versus the `list` O(n) lookup. Values that are intended as [constants should be named with ALL_CAPS_NAMES](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants). Functions should directly reference constants *iff* they are not meant to be replaced.

```
STOP_WORDS = {'com1', 'com2'}  # constant set of words
    
def clean_text(text_tokens):
    return [token for token in text_tokens if token not in STOP_WORDS]
    #                             directly access constant ^

clean_text(['hello', 'world', 'com1', 'com2'])
```

---

For small constants, it may be advantageous to provide them as a literal. Even CPython is able to optimise inline literals to actual constants.

```
def clean_text(text_tokens):
    return [
        token
        for token in text_tokens
        if token not in {'com1', 'com2'}
        #               ^ compiled as LOAD_CONST (frozenset({'com2', 'com1'}))
    ]

clean_text(['hello', 'world', 'com1', 'com2'])
```

The current optimiser converts `list` and `tuple` literals to `tuple` constants, and `set` and `frozenset` literals to `frozenset` constants

Comment: "Always prefer to create constants at global scope" - this is too strong (from **my** point of view). It has advantages you have described. But also some disadvantages, e.g. it may (depending on actual context) pollute the global scope, it may be modified accidentally etc.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario A is better if you want to pass different lists for `stop_words` as a parameter each time you call the function, while Scenario B only test it for `['com1','com2']`,which mean you only change this list when you edit the function itself.

In conclusion: Scenario A is better to test different lists and pass them as parameters in the function.